# how to find sum of the changing nCr*mCs sereis?

Tags: combinatorics

I am just stuck to find formula for the sum of the following series. **(m-q+1+i)C(i) * (n+q-1-i)C(n-i)** where i varies from 0 to p; p < n, p < m.

i.e****( !m-q+1-i/ !i * !m-q+1) * ( n + q-1-i / !q-1 * !n-i)****. i starts from 0 and goes upto p.